# Sufficient to check intersection of sub base elements with a dense set in compact open topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, duality-theorems

I am reading a book about duality and there was this following claim:
If I have a compact group G* (dual group of G, and G is discrete) with the compact open topology, then for any A, a subset of G* which contains the identity, it is sufficient to check non-empty intersection with any sub base elements of G*, in order to determine that A is dense in G. (i.e. any element of the form P(k,v) where k is compact in G and v open in T)
My question is why it is sufficient to check only sub base elements and not all open sets in G*?

Comment: Does *dual group* mean that $G^*$ is the group of all maps from $G$ to $\Bbb R$, or what is the codomain of the maps in $G^*$ ?

Comment: Hmm... Isn't the set $A$ of constant functions a counterexample?

Comment: Dual group G* is the group of all continuous homomorphisms from G to T where T is the circle group

Comment: As for the second question, the answer is no, since it is a homomorphism then a constant map will be just sent to 0

Comment: Oops, don't know what I was thinking.